# Can I restrict Amazon S3 Browser-Based Uploads by URL in my bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Based on: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html

Is there a way to limit a browser based upload to Amazon S3 such that it is rejected if it does not originate from my secure URL (i.e. https://www.someurl.com)?

Thanks!

Comment: Before answering please be familiar with the S3 Brower Based POST methodology as it is all clientside. Question is simply how to ensure post only comes from my domain.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to absolutely guarantee the post is coming from my website

That is impossible.

The web is stateless and a `POST` coming "from" a specific domain is just not a valid concept, because the `Referer:` header is trivial to spoof, and a malicious user most likely knows this.  Running through an EC2 server will gain you nothing, because it will tell you nothing new and meaningful.

The post policy document not only expires, it also can constrain the object key to a prefix or an exact match.  How is a malicious user going to defeat this?  They can't.

> in your client form you have encrypted/hashed versions of your credentials.

No, you do not.

What you have is a signature that attests to your authorization for S3 to honor the form post.  It can't feasibly be reverse-engineered such that the policy can be modified, and that's the point. The form has to match the policy, which can't be edited and still remain valid.

You generate this signature using information known only to you and AWS; specifically, the secret that accompanies your access key.

When S3 receives the request, it computes what the signature should have been.  If it's a match, then the privileges of the specific user owning that key are checked to see whether the request is authorized.

By constraining the object key in the policy, you prevent the user from uploading (or overwriting) any object other than the specific one authorized by the policy. Or the specific object ket prefix, in which case, you restrict the user from harm to anything not under that prefix.

If you are handing over a policy that allows any object key to be overwritten in the entire bucket, then you're solving the wrong problem by trying to constrain posts as coming "from" your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how the S3 service authenticates.

Your server would have a credentials file holding your access id and key and then your server signs the file as it is uploaded to your S3 bucket.

Amazon's S3 servers then check that the uploaded file has been signed by your access id and key.

This credentials file should never be publicly exposed anywhere and there's no way to get the keys off the wire.

In the case of browser based uploads your form should contain a signature that is passed to Amazon's S3 servers and authenticated against. This signature is generated from a combination of the upload policy, your access id and key but it is hashed so you shouldn't be able to get back to the secret key.

As you mentioned, this could mean that someone would be able to upload to your bucket from outside the confines of your app by simply reusing the signature in the `X-Amz-Signature` header.

This is what the policy's expiration header is for as it allows you to set a reasonably short expiration period on the form to prevent misuse.

So when a user goes to your upload page your server should generate a policy with a short expiration date (for example, 5 minutes after generation time). It should then create a signature from this policy and your Amazon credentials. From here you can now create a form that will post any data to your S3 bucket with the relevant policy and signature.

If a malicious user was to then attempt to copy the policy and signature and use that directly elsewhere then it would still expire 5 minutes after they originally landed on your upload page.

You can also use the policy to restrict other things such as the name of the file or mime types.

More detailed information is available in the AWS docs about [browser based uploads to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) and [how S3 authenticates requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html).

To further restrict where requests can come from you should look into enabling [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) permissions on your S3 bucket.

This allows you to specify which domain(s) each type of request may originate from.

Comment: Hi. If you go back and look at the link I posted at beginning of question you will see that the server is never touched in this use-case. S3 offers Browser Based uploads because you create a secure upload policy and in your client form you have encrypted/hashed versions of your credentials. They are never exposed but the upload/POST is determined by the policy. So I am afraid you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Added some specifics about how browser based POSTs are authenticated. Basically you generate the policy and signature on load of the upload page and then use this to control the expiration time.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was looking into the expiring signature as I use it elsewhere but I was worried a user could do alot of damage even in 30 seconds if they can copy & paste fast enough. But this was an excellent update. I still think the correct solution would be through the bucket policy to block POSTs unless coming from a whitelisted domain. - Thanks again.

Comment: I've just read up on CORS which covers exactly what you want. I hadn't ever spotted that before so I've learned something new too.

Comment: CORS does not stop the POST. I have CORS permissions set up on 5 buckets and am intimate with creating the CORS XML permissions. However the Browser Based Upload is apparently immune to CORS. I can even post from http://localhost. I was hoping CORS was the solution before posting the question today. It seems that Browser Based Uploads trump CORS.... Actually I believe Browser Based Posts pre-date CORS by years.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to barricade the door.  Remove the door.

A better solution IMHO would be to prevent any uploads at all directly to s3.
Meaning delete your s3 upload policy that allows strangers to upload.

1. Make them upload to one of your servers.
2. Validate the upload however you like.
3. If it is acceptable then your server could move the file to s3.